# Linking to the route in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to link to the route using this code in the view:

```
 <a href="url('/site/entry')">Entry here</a>
```

Previously in laravel using blade template i used this code which worked fine.

```
<a href="{{url('/site/entry')}}">Entry here</a>
```

what is the way here in yii framework?

Answer (score 1):

Yii offers two methods of creating urls:

- [createUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail)
- [createAbsoluteUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createAbsoluteUrl-detail)

Assume that you want to create relative url. You can create it with controller's method `createUrl()`. You can use `$this->createUrl(...)` where `$this` is instance of controller, or directly use `Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(...)`;

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/site/entry'); ?>">Entry here</a>

<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/site/entry'); ?>">Entry here</a>
```

Comment: it displayed unknown method. anything to declare?

Comment: Which way are you using? `$this->createUrl` or `Yii::app()->controller->createUrl`? And where are you using it? In view?

Comment: Ok, so do `var_dump($this)` and check what is output? This should be instance of `CController` or child class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/site/entry">Entry here</a>
```

Comment: Your method will not take advantage of Yii routing and *Friendly URL*